# Why won't schools allow students to repeat a year?

Tags: teen, education, school

In a little over a year time our child will have to pick a secondary education (in the Netherlands).
Throught friends with older children I have heard stories of children who were refused to repeat a year when they performed poorly. Insted they would either have to leave school or do the next year at a lower level.

I should explain here that in the Netherlands a child can go through secondary education on different levels, this will in turn decide if they can go to University after school or Higher Vocational Education, or some other kind of Vocational Education.

Back in my time the children who repeated a year invariably did so because they had spend the year smoking weed in the park and not doing their homework.
As a parent I don't see why in such cases a child should not repeat a year. By moving to a lower level the child will miss out even if they later return/continue education at a higher level. This is because they will have missed several years of study at a higher level. For math especially this is a problem since they will have missed some important topics.

Is this a policy and if so what is the rationale? And is this just in the Netherelands or does it happen in other countries?

Comment: That seems more like a question for the school principal or local politicians than it does the Parenting SE.

Comment: Not an answer, as I can't back it up, but I believe that it is an informal policy that results from how the schools are financed. It is just more cost-effective to have the child go to a lower level and complete that within the nominal time than to let the child re-do a year at the academic level they are actually capable of.

Comment: @DennisHackethal you are not wrong, and I've heard the explanation of BartvanIngenSchenau from other people, but I have not been able to confirm it with sources and I'm curious if this is local to the Netherlands or local to Europe. And if so why?

Comment: The mods edited my previous comment without my approval or so much as notifying me. They removed a substantial part and thus changed the meaning significantly.

Comment: @Ivana that's a thing in the US as well. The given rationale is that apparently there are some studies that show it doesn't help the student on average, and makes them more likely to eventually drop out of school.

Comment: This is a country dependent policy, already in Germany it is possible to repeat a year if you do badly enough. However, secondary schooling has similar tiers and if you are at the highest tier the general suggestion usually is to switch to a lower tier and not to repeat a year.